# Store entire application config file as kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have a config json file in my application. This is single json file which has all configs required for my nodejs application. I have many connections to many db'. I even have bifurcation like stage and production. I don't want to create secret for each variable. I want to dump my complete JSON as secret. So that i can directly pick it up from there and use in my application. 
Anyway i can achieve it? I think its a generic problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to put the entire config file under `stringData` in the secret. Something like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  config.json: |
   <your config goes here>
```

Now you can just [mount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) the secret onto the pod , and you can read this config file.

While this work, it might be harder to use with GitOps solution, which usually requires you to encrypt the entire secret content. Using [Kamus](https://kamus.soluto.io), you can create templated config file with encrypted values, in the following format:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: encrypted-secrets-cm
data:
  key: 4AD7lM6lc4dGvE3oF+5w8g==:WrcckiNNOAlMhuWHaM0kTw== //encrypted
  template.ejs: |
     <%- secrets["key"] %>
     hello
```

And use the [init container](https://github.com/Soluto/kamus/tree/master/init-container) to create the config file with the decrypted values. The value with the encrypted items can be safely committed to git.

Comment: Does it encrypt the values? or is it plain text.

Comment: Regular secrets are not encrypted, but base64 encoded. `stringData` is a simple synthetic sugar to save you from encoding the data.

Comment: you don't need to encode, Kubernetes will encode it for you

Comment: When i use as a environment variable, when i use in application do i get it back as JSON object or just string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> create cm secret --from-file=APPLICATION_CONFIG=./<your-config>
```

Mount that into certain path and you can read your config from those path.

Answer (score 0):

We use HOCON config file format, it allows to `include` some values from other files. So application just reads the single config file, and HOCON reader automatically reads other files and fills in values from there.

That way, we provide config as a file from a k8s ConfigMap, and secrets as another file from a k8s Secret.